# Coloring PHP while editing C++

Tags: php, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I am currently writing a PHP file that prints to a C++ .h file. I would like for the PHP parts of the file to be highlighted with a pink background while I am editing the C++ code outside of PHP.

Currently what I have is:

```
(make-face 'font-lock-special-macro-face)
(set-face-background 'font-lock-special-macro-face "pink")
(defun add-custom-keyw()
  "adds a few special keywords for c and c++ modes"
  ;
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
   '(
     ("<\\?[^\\?]*\\?>" . 'font-lock-special-macro-face )
     ; more of those would go here
     )
   )
 )
```

However, this only highlights the sections of PHP enclosed in `<?= ?>`, i.e. the echo statements. Furthermore, it only highlights them if there are no curly braces or square brackets enclosed in such a section of PHP. What I would like to happen is for emacs to highlight the entirety of PHP enclosed by `<?= ?>` and for it to highlight PHP code enclosed by `<?php ?>` whenever the cursor resides outside PHP code.